# Text in marker of MapBox

Tags: text, marker, mapbox

I want to write some text like '1234' in marker on MapBox's map. 
Here marker-symbol property allows only one character.
Any idea of this please share.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in code with Leaflet's [L.DivIcon constructor](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon). The example on Mapbox developer pages demonstrate this: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/divicon/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I want to retain all the functionalities of marker.  If you could suggest how can I do that? i.e. title, description etc.

Comment: can we put text inside the marker. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035655/custom-marker-with-dialog-box

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the "textcontent" method.

Something around these lines:

```
    const el = document.createElement("div");
    el.className = 'marker';
    const width = 10;
    const height = 50;
    el.style.width = `${width}px`;
    el.style.height = `${height}px`;
    el.textContent = "my-text";
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(["your coordinates"])
```