# Custom marker with dialog box

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

[image][image]

How do I achieve dialog like those shown above. So far this is what I can do right now

```
map.addLayer({
    "id": "markers",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "markers",
    "interactive": true,
    "layout": {
        "text-field": "{price2}",
        "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
        "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
        "text-anchor": "top",
        "text-size": 12,
        "text-letter-spacing": 0.05,
        "icon-image": "marker-15"
    },
    "paint": {
        "text-color": "#fff",
        "text-halo-width": 2,
        "text-halo-color": "rgb(11, 148, 68)"
    }
});
```

Do I have to use studio to have such effect?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see to do this is to use markers with a [custom HTML Element](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/). You won't be able to use a source though.